# Get the cumulative most frequent status for specific column in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, numpy, count, cumulative-sum

I have a dataframe:

```
# create example df
df = pd.DataFrame(index=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
df['ID'] = [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2]
df['election_date'] = pd.date_range("01/01/2010", periods=8, freq="M")
df['status'] = ['b','a','b','c','a','d','d','b']

# sort values
df.sort_values(['election_date'], inplace=True, ascending=False)
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

df 

ID  election_date   status
0   2   2010-08-31    b
1   2   2010-07-31    d
2   2   2010-06-30    d
3   2   2010-05-31    a
4   1   2010-04-30    c
5   1   2010-03-31    b
6   1   2010-02-28    a
7   1   2010-01-31    b
```

I would like to get the **cumulative** most frequent status for column `status` for each `ID`. This is what I would expect:

```
    ID  election_date   status  cum_most_freq_status
0   2   2010-08-31        b          d
1   2   2010-07-31        d          d
2   2   2010-06-30        d          a
3   2   2010-05-31        a          NaN
4   1   2010-04-30        c          b
5   1   2010-03-31        b          a 
6   1   2010-02-28        a          b
7   1   2010-01-31        b          NaN
```

**Interpretation:**

- for `2010-01-31` the value is `NaN` because there was no `status` value in the past. The same works for `2010-05-31`.
- for `2010-03-31` the most frequent status in the past was a and b. Therefore we take the most recent value, which was `a`.

How would you do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first make a DataFrame with `ID` and `election_date` as its index, and one-hot-encoded `status` values, then calculate `cumsum`.

We want to pick the most recent status if there is a tie in counts, so I'm adding a small number (less than 1) to `cumsum` for the current status, so when we apply `idxmax` it will pick up the most recent status in case there's a tie.

After finding the most frequent cumulative status with `idxmax` we can `merge` with the original DataFrame:

```
# make one-hot-encoded status dataframe
z = (df
         .groupby(['ID', 'election_date', 'status'])
         .size().unstack().fillna(0))

# break ties to choose most recent
z = z.groupby(level=0).cumsum() + (z * 1e-4)

# shift by 1 row, since we only count previous status occurrences
z = z.groupby(level=0).shift()

# merge
df.merge(z.idxmax(axis=1).to_frame('cum_most_freq_status').reset_index())
```

Output:

```
   ID election_date status cum_most_freq_status
0   2    2010-08-31      b                    d
1   2    2010-07-31      d                    d
2   2    2010-06-30      d                    a
3   2    2010-05-31      a                  NaN
4   1    2010-04-30      c                    b
5   1    2010-03-31      b                    a
6   1    2010-02-28      a                    b
7   1    2010-01-31      b                  NaN
```

Comment: Sorry, just realized that after applying your code to my dataframe, I lose some rows. The lengths of my dataframe changes. I have no NaN values in the my column ``status``. Therefore I have no idea what is happening. Appart from this detail, everything works great

Comment: I apply your code to multiple columns in a row. Afterwards, I have less rows then I have started with

Comment: @PParker Interesting, if you can share some sample dataset where it happens (just a small sample where you lose at least one row), I can check what could be the reason

Comment: Well, let me first try to break it down into smaller pieces. I'll come back to you soon!

Comment: @PParker Actually, without looking at any data, I would suspect the problem could be in the `merge` step, as it tries to join on all overlapping columns, and if some values in the overlapping columns are different, it will result in rows being dropped. As a first step, I would check that we're using different names in `to_frame('cum_most_freq_status')` for each column and that it doesn't overlap with existing column names in `df`

Comment: If that doesn't help, then yes, let me check when you have some data & code sample where it happens